# How to return from user define method to delegate method

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, nsarray

I'm implementing the in-app purchase. And I got the problem while executing the delegate methods of store kit.

Here is my code as following:

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {

    NSLog(@"Received products results...");   
    NSLog(@"response.products.......%@",response.products);
    self.products = response.products;
    self.request = nil;    

     proUpgradeProduct = [_products count] == 1 ? [[_products objectAtIndex:0] retain] : nil;

     if (proUpgradeProduct)
     {
     NSLog(@"Product title: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.localizedTitle);
     NSLog(@"Product description: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.localizedDescription);
     NSLog(@"Product price: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.price);
     NSLog(@"Product id: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.productIdentifier);
     }

     NSLog(@"products.....%@",_products);

     for (NSString *invalidProductId in response.invalidProductIdentifiers)
     {
     NSLog(@"Invalid product id: %@" , invalidProductId);
     }


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kProductsLoadedNotification object:_products];    

    [self buyProductIdentifier:proUpgradeProduct.productIdentifier];

}


- (void)buyProductIdentifier:(NSString *)productIdentifier {
    if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments])
    {
    NSLog(@"Buying %@...", productIdentifier);

    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:productIdentifier];
   [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"StoreKit" message:@"You are not authorised to purchase from AppStore"
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }

}

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Control is not shifting to `- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions` in `(void)buyProductIdentifier:(NSString *)productIdentifier` - method.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should set `SKPaymentTransactionObserver` of `defaultQueue`:

   `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:manager];`
2. Method `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:` will be called only after `StoreKit` did end working with transaction(s) in your `defaultQueue` : when user canceled or purchased (or transaction was restored) the product.

Comment: where should i write [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];? i have written this in (void)buyProductIdentifier:(NSString *)productIdentifier

Comment: here i am getting problem that when i click on third pay button i am getting called by four methods..